# Subdomains tree implementation

Tags: c++, c, go, search, tree

I am working on golang implementation of subdomains tags storage (looks like multimap). Not so clear for me what type of tree should I use for implement following logic:

```
    tree := NewTree()
    tree.AddTag("com", 1)
    tree.AddTag("google.com", 2)
    tree.AddTag("google.com", 3)
    tree.AddTag("www.google.com", 4)

    var ret []int
    ret = tree.GetTags("msn.com") // ret = [1]
    ret = tree.GetTags("www.msn.com") // ret = [1]
    ret = tree.GetTags("google.com") // ret = [1,2,3]
    ret = tree.GetTags("www.google.com") // ret = [1,2,3,4]
    ret = tree.GetTags("mail.google.com") // ret = [1,2,3]
    ret = tree.GetTags("debug.www.google.com") // ret = [1,2,3,4]
```

This task is different than suffix search, for example "msn.com" belongs to "com" and "www.google.com" belongs to "google.com" and "www.google.com".

If someone could to point me to c/c++/golang sources I would also appreciate.

Comment: you should use a prefix tree but reverse the strings, then it becomes a simple prefix search. you basically search for `moc.elgoog` and get all the sub domains and their tags.

Comment: re implementations, for C you can use this which I wrote https://github.com/RedisLabs/triemap or a similar one from antirez https://github.com/antirez/rax. Both are used heavily in production and are stable and good, and roughly the same speed. Mine has the advantage of having a collision callback when inserting, that you can use to append more "tags" to the value field.

Comment: I don't follow how ```moc.elgoog.www``` will match ```moc.elgoog```, this is different than match ```moc.elgoog``` with ```moc.elgoog.www```, so this is partially suffix match.

Comment: you want the other way, no? in any case you can index both ways and query however you want.